# Is it possible to catch or log a toast message from adb shell

Tags: android, adb

Can I know, if an app produces a toast message from adb shell.Thanks in advance.Just black box testing do not have the source code(Not from Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is something like that, but you can create BroadcastReceiver in your app which display a toast, and send intent via adb shell

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.your.broadcast.intent --es toast_text "test from adb"
```